# TeamCity 8 xcode 5 agent code sign error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, teamcity, agent

I am trying to run Xcode using TeamCity but I am getting a Code Sign error. Even though the provision profile and certificate exists on my machine. I can build it on my iPhone. This is the error I am getting:

> Step 1/1: Xcode Project [09:36:16][Step 1/1] PRAnalytics (CLEAN)
>
> [09:36:16][PRAnalytics (CLEAN)] [BEROR]Code Sign error: No matching
>   provisioning profile found: Your build settings specify a provisioning
>   profile with the UUID “8A7A8B79-####-####-####-C39537A6A156”, however,
>   no such provisioning profile was found.
>
> [09:36:16][PRAnalytics (CLEAN)] [BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is
>   required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
>
> [09:36:16][Step 1/1] Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profile
>   found: Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with the
>   UUID “8A7A8B79-####-####-####-C39537A6A156”, however, no such
>   provisioning profile was found.
>
> [09:36:16][Step 1/1] CodeSign error: code signing is required for
>   product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'
>
> [09:36:16][Step 1/1] Step Xcode Project failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out. My agent was in HD/AGENT. When i moved it to HD/USER/DESKTOP/AGENT, it began to work. Seems like Agent should be in the USER directory.

Comment: I added the second build agent for a TeamCity server installed on a Mac in /Library folder (iOS build) and provisioning profiles only worked on the second agent after moving the agent to /Users/whatever/ directory. Curiously, default agent remains in /Library dir. and has no problems. Good call!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue, which was due to two main reasons, Xcode when invoked from teamcity looks its resources from the System & not the user, so to fix at least get sure that you did the following:-

1-Ensure the project is building successfully from Xcode to real target.
-In KeyChain

2-Copy all the development certificates & credentials form your user folder to the system folder

3-Copy all the Provisioning profiles existing in
*Users//Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles*
to
*System/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles*

Create the missing folders if they don’t exist below 'Library'

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked build settings properly. Check your plist for identifier. And provisioning profile and code signing settings in Build settings. Make sure you are setting right provisioning and certificate.

[image]

Comment: Yes, i just checked. Everything is correct. I can run, build, and archive in Xcode.

Comment: Did you check in xcode -> Organizer -> Profiles -> Is this provisioning profile installed on your system or not?  UUID “8A7A8B79-####-####-####-C39537A6A156”

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5, there is no profiles form organizer. I used iPhone configuration utility to check if there is profiles with that UUID, and there is.